# Wait for complete statement or function in winform of c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I developing winform (c#) to read html form website.

When i click button, Textbox1 don't set text after 1 seconds. It wait unit the end forech.

Now i want, function will set text for textbox in 1 seconds.
how do it?

this is the code:

**when kick button1:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string url = "http://truyentranh8.com/danh_sach_truyen/";
     var web = new HtmlWeb();
     var doc = web.Load(url);
     foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr/td[@class='tit']/a[@class='tipsy']"))
     {
         textBox1.Text += node.InnerText + "\n";
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You mean append text each one second?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(100);` is 1/10 s. `Thread.Sleep(1000);` is 1 s.

Comment: ago, i have set Thread.Sleep(5000); Textbox1 don't set text after 5 seconds.

Comment: Do not use Thread.Sleep on an event thread..

Comment: thanks U for answer my question. I have solotion form everybody

Comment: You should consider using http://watin.org/

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Sleep` in your case puts the main thread in in sleep mode. It can't update the UI till it gets released and the `button1_Click` method is over. So you don't see text changes per second. All you'll see is `Text` being updated all at once.

So make it asynchronous. If you're using .Net 4.5, you can use async/await and make life simple.

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string url = "http://truyentranh8.com/danh_sach_truyen/";
     var web = new HtmlWeb();
     var doc = web.Load(url);
     foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr/td[@class='tit']/a[@class='tipsy']"))
     {
         textBox1.Text += node.InnerText + "\n";
         await Task.Delay(1000);
     }
 }
```

If you are interested I have [written article on this subject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/737164/Enumerate-Collection-with-Delay).

Answer (score 2):

Do *not* use `Thread.Sleep` on an event thread for this task.

The problem is that the *UI is not getting a chance to update* as it redraws on the thread *that is blocked*. As such the UI update only appears *after* all the thread-blocking code ends and the Click handler is exited.

Use an appropriate [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, or if feeling hackish, read up about [DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx). Alternatively, consider doing the long running task in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) - the UserState of the Progress event can be used to report partial updates, already marshaled back to the appropriate thread.

Comment: Do You have solution for my problem? do U can share code for me?

Comment: @toan I would probably use a BackgroundWorker; heavy (ie. long-running) work does *not* belong on the UI thread. You may be able to get by with DoEvents - but it really screams *kludge*.

Comment: @toan note that user2864740 would also properly post updates from background thread to UI thread (which is not mentioned in post or comments). Watch out for issues when you directly touch UI from non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use DoEvents to refresh the form every time you change something on design

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string url = "http://truyentranh8.com/danh_sach_truyen/";
     var web = new HtmlWeb();
     var doc = web.Load(url);
     foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr/td[@class='tit']/a[@class='tipsy']"))
     {
         textBox1.Text += node.InnerText + "\n";
        Application.DoEvents();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please [don't recommend DoEvents](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/)

Comment: +0: Advice to cause possible re-entrancy into event handler is not the best cure for the issue... Possible, but definitely not one to follow.

Comment: Well, i've used it many times and it never made me trouble! But Since You guys recommend no to, then I take my answer back.